# Rails Form for another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form in pages/contact and want to send the data to another model called ContactForm instead of Pages model, so i guess this is outside the basic convention.. it looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @contact_form, url: pages_contact_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
...
...
<% end %>

class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def contact
        @contact_form = ContactForm.new(contact_form_params)    
    end
end
```

I created this route

```
  post 'pages/contact' => 'pages#contact'
```

and it all seems to work fine, but no data is recorded. In the local server i can see is processing the POST but is not doing any SQL Transaction.. why??

```
Started POST "/pages/contact" for ::1 at 2016-06-22 15:58:47 -0300
Processing by PagesController#contact as HTML
Processing by PagesController#contact as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"WIb3jXmkxP0mxRPSPU0Yj050fFwCQOlm9FatCFiGuSrEaoRNXNtmn/w0ZOMtsZsRUwjq4NQweV+d56T5nFxL5Q==", "contact_form"=>{"name"=>"Diego", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"", "subject"=>"", "message"=>"Hoal"}, "commit"=>"Create Contact form"}
```

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WIb3jXmkxP0mxRPSPU0Yj050fFwCQOlm9FatCFiGuSrEaoRNXNtmn/w0ZOMtsZsRUwjq4NQweV+d56T5nFxL5Q==", "contact_form"=>{"name"=>"Diego", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"", "subject"=>"", "message"=>"Hoal"}, "commit"=>"Create Contact form"}
  Rendered pages/contact.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you define `contact_forms_param` are you reading from `params[:contact_form]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the local server i can see is processing the POST but is not doing
>   any SQL Transaction.. why?

No `SQL` is done as long as no transaction is requested. What your `contact_form` action does is assigning parameters to a variable, but this variable is not requested to be validated and saved to your database. So it is simply passed over to the view...

What you're intrested of is:

```
@contact_form = ContactForm.new(contact_form_params)
if @contact_form.save
  # render success
else
  # render errors
end
```