# Form for different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form in pages/contact.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @contact_form, url: pages_contact_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

,but i want to send data to a different model, i have created it as ContactForm and it has no controller.

So in the Pages controller i have something like this (all simplified for the sake of this question..

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def contact
        @contact_form = ContactForm.new(contact_form_params)
        @contact_form.save
    end

    private

    def contact_form_params
        params.require(:contact_form).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :subject, :message)
    end
end
```

When i try to load the page (pages/contact) i get this error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: contact_form
```

If i take out the (contact_form_params) for the white listing the page renders fine but of course all data is sent as nil. I can see on the server though, that the hash does have the contact_form so i don´t what else to do..

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qjfdt/4PgAjImpbB8Q3wJIJZnvQddIB1DmD0NdER6aM2265323AiahJr4fDh8XO6nyUISMsEEExn0f3EFcsbbA==", "contact_form"=>{"name"=>"Pedrinho", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"", "subject"=>"", "message"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Contact form"}
```

please help!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, looks like that is linked with your [form for another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976319/rails-form-for-another-model) topic. Okay, speaking broader, the problem is that you're trying to mix up two things: **creation** of an object and its **building**. [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) teaches us to map those things to different controller actions, e.g. `pages/build_contact` and `pages/create_contact`. The first one would contain a plain old

```
def build_contact
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new
end
```

while the latter one would build a contact form based on passed params and try to save it:

```
def create_contact
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new(contact_form_params)
  if @contact_form.save
    # redirect somewhere
  else
    # render build_contact view with @contact_form and show errors there
  end
end
```

Note that this requires you to change your view files and routes accordingly.

Well let's assume you've got a strong reason not to have two separate methods.

**DISCLAIMER**: I would never ever advice you to do that, but it is possible with conditional logics. You should check whether `contact_form` parameters are obtained, and in case they are there, try to save an object. The opposite case leads us to building a new one. Note that this becomes an ugly variation of two methods option, which was explained above.

```
def contact
    if got_contact_form?
      @contact_form = ContactForm.new(contact_form_params)
      @contact_form.save
      # hint: what you gonna do if your save call failed due to validation errors?
    else
      @contact_form = ContactForm.new
    end
end

private

def got_contact_form?
  # check if you've got required params
  params["contact_form"].present?
end
```